# How to convert unicode charater during mail reading using Java Mail?

Tags: java, unicode, jakarta-mail, unicode-string

I am trying to read mail threw JavaScript and done successfully. Now issue is that when the inline image is present into the mail at that time format of the mail add one zero width space using "=E2=80=8B" this character and I cannot read this properly.

I got `?` in place of this code which is create bug for my application how I can remove this `?` mark and how I can decode `=E2=80=8B` this code using Java

```
        Message Content :- <html>
     <head></head> 
 <body> 
 <div dir="ltr"> 
      <img src="/account/images/companydata/indies/inlineemailattach/1413183522383_subaru_hd_logo_wallpapers.png" height="264" width="440" /> 12 27 
 <br />? 
 <br /> 
 </div>  
</body>
  </html>
```

In above output we can see the `?` after `br` tag. How can I decode this?

Answer (score 0):

The `=E2=80=8B` is the quoted-printable encoding of a character, which JavaMail should decode for you using the JDK's charset handling, assuming the charset was set properly in the message.  What's the charset attribute on the Content-Type header of the message content?  Can you post the entire MIME content of a message that shows this problem?  From JavaMail, use `message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt"))` and then post the content of msg.txt.